# Why arent javascript , jquery and css files working properly in MVC4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a web site using bootsrap and mvc4 but unfortunatly not only bootstrap files but any js file or css file i include in the layout file doesnt act properly. I dont know whats going on can some on suggest me what to do?

i have created a bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/new").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.js"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css1").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
```

and i have added them to the lay out

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/new")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css1")
```

I,m trying to add navigation bar and and a carousel there are not working properly

Comment: post what you have written.

Comment: How is anyone going to possibly know what's going wrong if all you tell us is that it "doesn't act properly"? You need to **clearly** describe your problem and what you've tried to do about it.

Comment: As long as you put the link and script tags in the <head> of the _Layout page, any controller/views that use that _Layout should also see the files.

Comment: I see 3 typos in your code snippet... Do those exist in your real code?

Comment: I have used them in <head> tag KidBilly

Comment: Normally script files (like jquery.js) would be under `Scripts` and not `Content`. Are you sure you have them all in the correct places in the project?

Comment: Also when i try to do this an Index Out of range exception from appears for bootstrap.css file

Comment: @user3796259: You should not have changed the css bundle, so should not have got that error, just change the `script` one I mentioned. Please follow the guidelines below and, if you still have problems, provide more of your code/HTML etc.

Comment: Still unclear, "there are not working properly" ... please show your carrusel code, show your nav bar code, etc. all parts involved, in summary form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much to go on, so here are a few tips for working with bundles:

**Bundles names:**

Make sure the bundle name does not match an actual folder or file in the project as IIS will return the actual folder/file in preference to the bundle.

To avoid this I use bundles names like these (as I have no styles or bundles folders/files):

```
@Styles.Render("~/styles/MainLayout")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MainLayout")
```

**File placement:**

Usually your script files would be under a `scripts` folder in the project and not `content`. Content is typically for images and styles.

e.g make sure your files are in these locations in your project:

```
/Scripts/bootstrap.js

/Content/bootstrap.css
```

The matching bundles (keeping a little of your naming) would look like:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/new").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/css1").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
```

and rendered with:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/new")
@Styles.Render("~/styles/css1")
```

**Other scripts?**

Scripts are often dependent on other scripts, so make sure you include those *before* the ones that use them.

e.g. jQuery needs to go in earlier than most scripts if used:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/new")
@Styles.Render("~/styles/css1")
```

Note: *Now if none of this helps you need to help us help you, by providing your entire layout file, your entire `BundleConfig.cs` and even a screenshot of your project explorer window in visual studio.* :)